# How to fix error "SQLexception was unhandled by user code incorrect syntax near 'FROM'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Anyone can help me on where the 'FROM' error is would be greatly

Here my code vb is problem

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Private Sub ButtonOK_Click() Handles ButtonOK.Click

    sql = "SELECT Drug.DrugID, Drug.DrugName, Categories.CategoryName, " & _
            "Suppliers.CompanyName, Drug.UnitPrice, Drug.UnitsInstock, " & _
          "FROM Drug " & _
            "LEFT JOIN Categories " & _
                "ON (Drug.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID) " & _
            "LEFT JOIN Suppliers " & _
                "ON (Drug.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID) " & _
            "WHERE Drug.ExpireDate BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2"
    command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

    Dim dt1 As String = GetDateTime(DateTimePicker1)
    Dim dt2 As String = GetDateTime(DateTimePicker2)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt1", dt1)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("dt2", dt2)

    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    dataSt = New DataSet()
    adapter.Fill(dataSt, "expire")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dataSt.Tables("expire")

    DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = _
        Color.PowderBlue

    For i = 0 To headerText.Length - 1
        DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText = headerText(i)
    Next

    ButtonToExcel.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Here's the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

This may work, Just remove the extra ',' from the end of second line.

```
sql = "SELECT Drug.DrugID, Drug.DrugName, Categories.CategoryName, " & _
        "Suppliers.CompanyName, Drug.UnitPrice, Drug.UnitsInstock " & _
      "FROM Drug " & _
        "LEFT JOIN Categories " & _
            "ON (Drug.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID) " & _
        "LEFT JOIN Suppliers " & _
            "ON (Drug.SupplierID = Suppliers.SupplierID) " & _
        "WHERE Drug.ExpireDate BETWEEN @dt1 AND @dt2"
```

Comment: Doesn't work bro. There was another problem.

there is my problem 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: `DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText = headerText(i)`

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Check that your query may not bring any data or headerText is null.

Comment: It seems the `headerText` array length is greater than the number of columns returned. `headerText.Length` must be the same as DataGridView1.Columns.Count in order for your code to work properly and avoid the index out of range error.